# IR 40kHz receiver

Tags: sensors

These days I'm trying to build IR 40kHz long range receiver. I use ir phototransistor. I don't want to use components like TSOP... I need to make
daylight filter and intensify filtred signal because out of this sensor I wanna use with some microcontroller. Can someone help me? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close this question because questions which are more of generic electrical engineering questions and have no real relation to robotics are better off at Electrical Engineering.

Comment: It would better go on engineering.stackexchange, as this as daylight filters have nothing to do with electrical engineering. But I have an idea for this question: "Do it, and come back to explain any problem you'll have". SE is a Q/A site, not a place to delegate sensor design.

Comment: I have flagged this question for migration to E.E. SE.

Answer (score 1):

IR receiver circuits based on phototransistors were widely used in TV sets before the advent of integrated modules, like TSOP, in late '80s. You can take inspiration from old time TV service manuals. In general the phototransistor is polarized via a >100k resistor on the collector, then you need a high-pass filter with high input impedance to reject the effects of ambient IR sources, amplify, bandpass at about 40 kHz and at last shmitt-trigger to a square wave.